# Как правильно в SVG реализовать тег <image> как фоновую картинку

Tags: css3, svg

Дамы и Господа, есть такой пример

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 700">
     <style>
    svg{background:red;}
  </style>
     <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/keh4g.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </svg>
```

И как видим в примере. все работает.  Но если данный пример реализовать, как отдельный файл *****.svg  и использовать его как фоновую картинку...

Пример реализации:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../binary/image/svg/fon.svg);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
```

То результат таков: (см. фото ниже )

[image: Результат]

Вопрос, что не так в моих действиях и почему такое поведение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно закодировать изображение в `base64`:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <style>
    svg {
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
  <image xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,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=" width="50%" height="100%" x="100" y=""/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

В примере ниже  файл `*.svg` находится на сетевом ресурсе. Это лого SVG на `wikipedia`

Чтобы использовать его в качестве фона HTML странички подключаем его с помощью CSS:

`background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg);`

Чтобы увидеть, что этот файл лого работает действительно, как фон, добавляем сверху текст.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg);
  background-size:cover;
  }
p {
font-family:serif; 
font-size:3em;
text-indent:50px;
color:dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <p >I love SVG</p>
</div>
```

Ещё пример, где на фон SVG, накладывается сверху анимация svg

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg);
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" > 
 <circle cx="15%" cy="15%" r="7.5%" fill="green" fill-opacity="0.7" >
 <animate id="horiz" attributeName="cx" begin="0.3s;vert.end" values="15%;85%;15%" dur="4s" />
 <animate id="vert" attributeName="cy" begin="horiz.end" values="15%;85%;15%" dur="4s" />
 </circle>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Тоже подумывал о таком варианте, но захотелось добиться результата с помощью `<image/>`

Comment: @St1myL так с <image нет никаких проблем, если внутри svg, так как это команда svg/ А вот для HTML надо использовать <img>