# Не отображается image в SVG

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, svg, изображения

Нужно с помощью JavaScript засунуть картинку внутрь SVG, при помещении тега image в SVG содержимое xlink:href игнорируется и не отображается. Ради интереса засунул image в body, все прекрасно работает, но картинку нужно использовать именно в SVG. Мой способ:

```
var svg = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "svg");
svg.setAttribute("width",200);
svg.setAttribute("height",200);
svg.setAttribute("id","svg");

document.getElementById('body').appendChild(svg);

var img = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "image");
img.setAttribute("width", 200);
img.setAttribute("height", 200);
img.setAttribute("x", 0);
img.setAttribute("y", 0);
img.setAttribute("xlink:href", https://image.jpeg);
```

Comment: а что это у вас за адрес картинки  ? `https://image.jpeg` вы же понимаете что нету такого адреса ?

Comment: `hlink:href=""` указываете реальный  либо абсолютный путь либо от корня

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно в SVG реализовать тег <image> как фоновую картинку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795098/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2-svg-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3-image-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: Не стоит закрывать данный вопрос, так как он не подходит на роль дубликата явно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить `xlink`:

```js
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var xlink = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
var svg = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "svg");
svg.setAttribute("width", 200);
svg.setAttribute("height", 200);
svg.style.border = "1px solid red";

document.body.appendChild(svg);

var img = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "image");
img.setAttributeNS(xlink, 'xlink:href', "https://via.placeholder.com/200x200");

svg.appendChild(img);
```